# How can i write a reset function

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I am looking for a way to reset my form when a user edit the value's and hits the reset button.

My form contains:
2 textfields
4 checkboxes

The value's from this 6 elements i made in my model:

```
    public class MyModel
    {
        public MyModel()
        {
            Field1 = 8;
            Checkbox1 = true;
            Checkbox2 = true;
            Checkbox3 = true;
            Checkbox4 = true;
            Field2 = 1; 
        }

        [DisplayName("TextField 1")]
        [Range(4, 64, ErrorMessage = "Test Error")]
        public int Field1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("CheckBox 1")]
        public bool Checkbox1 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("CheckBox 2")]
        public bool Checkbox2 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("CheckBox 3")]
        public bool Checkbox3 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("CheckBox 4")]
        public bool Checkbox4 { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("TextField 2")]
        [Range(1, 50, ErrorMessage = "Test Error")]
        public int Field2 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

So by examle when a user unchecks checkbox 1 and edit value 1 from Field2 to 199 and hits the reset button all the elements are reset to the value's from MyModel()

Who can help me with this?

Comment: A reset button doesn't need any client side code.

Comment: Is it possible with client side code?

Comment: Of course it's possible: `<input type="button" onclick="this.form.reset();" value="Reset">` or `<input type="reset">`. Your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Just use an [`<input type="reset" />`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/reset). You don't need jQuery or a refresh, this functionality has been built into browsers since the marquee tag, at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually really easy if you don't want to do it client side, it'll just reload the form. However, I'm guessing you **want** to do this client side.

If you don't want to go down the MVVM route (KnockoutJS etc), then this is the basic idea (in jQuery):

```
$(function() {
   // You can make this more efficient by holding the element Ids in the array and setting their values in a loop.
   var prevValues = {};
   prevValues.checkbox1 = $('#checkbox1').is(":selected"); // true or false

   $('#reset').on("click", function() {
       // reset values here
       $('#checkbox1').prop("checked", prevValues.checkbox1);
   });
});


<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

<input type="button" id="reset" />
```